# HTML and JavaScript "this"

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code right here..

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="0">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="1">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have this JavaScript over here when you click on one of the links:

```
alert(this.id);
```

Question: is it possible to determine which "A" tag was clicked, without setting extra "id" attribute for links? With JavaScript it would be like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[number];
```

And I need that number from "this".

I hope you understand what I meant. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you tried target or currentTarget ?

Comment: (reference): [ids](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) *must begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])`* ([see docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name))

Comment: currentTarget throws undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding DOM node index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378365/finding-dom-node-index)

Comment: @Yoshi: Not anymore in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is less elegant, but working, solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = function() {
            var index = FindIndex(this);
            alert("index: " + index);
            return false;
        };
    }
};

function FindIndex(oLink) {
    var listItem = oLink.parentNode;
    var oList = listItem.parentNode;
    var allItems = oList.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
        if (allItems[i] === listItem)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/nXNNr/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
var index = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.indexOf(this.parentNode);

NodeList.prototype.indexOf = function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == obj) return i;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: One note: indexOf is not supported in IE. There are JS functions on the web that emulates it for IE and use native implementation if possible. Here is one example of such function http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2437

Comment: Here's a good fix for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Comment: `childNodes` is a NodeList, not an array, so it doesn't have an `indexOf` method. And this would include text nodes, including white space, which probably isn't what you want. Edit: and `this` is always the link, which is always the first element in the parent, so it would always be `0` anyway.

Comment: For some reason it throws error: this.parentNode.childNodes.indexOf(this) is not a function

Comment: Try again =)! (just add the prototype).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'indexOf' on Chrome.

Comment: Got it working like this - var index = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.indexOf(this.parentNode); but it returns 1,3,5.

Comment: @nuclear that's because text nodes that are also part of the list, in addition to the list items. See my answer and test case.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
<a href="#" onclick='doSomething(this)'>
```

*Edit*

After re-reading your question, it appears you want something along the lines of @Tim van Elsloo, but I'll leave this up for information purposes anyway.

*Edit 2*

After re-re-reading your question, are you just looking for GET?

```
<a href='?clicked=1'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Tim van Elsloo solution is what I am looking for.