# JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container

Tags: javascript, html, dom, parent-child

I need to find an index of element inside its container by object reference. Strangely, I cannot find an easy way. No jQuery please - only DOM.

```
UL
 LI
 LI
 LI - my index is 2
 LI
```

Yes, I could assign IDs to each element and loop through all nodes to match the ID but it seems a bad solution. Isn't there something nicer?

So, say I have an object reference to the third LI as in the example above. How do I know it is index 2?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you need to get the index? hover.. etc ??

Comment: why not perform a previousSibling on the li reference until you hit null?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding DOM node index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378365/finding-dom-node-index)

Comment: I think it would be easy if you add custom attribute to the li element. For example, <li index="0">, <li index="1"> and you can access it easily.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You could make usage of `Array.prototype.indexOf`. For that, we need to somewhat "cast" the `HTMLNodeCollection` into a true `Array`. For instance:

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('list').children );
```

Then we could just call:

```
nodes.indexOf( liNodeReference );
```

Example:

```js
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('list').children ),
    liRef = document.getElementsByClassName('match')[0];

console.log( nodes.indexOf( liRef ) );
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li class="match">bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Note: `.childNodes` and `.children` are different things. `.children` is a subset, a list of all `ElementNodes` only.

Comment: The [`previousElementSibling` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container#comment29654968_11762728) is better because it will exclude text nodes and will return the index of the element that you expect.

Comment: ES6 syntax: `const index = [...el.parentNode.children].indexOf(el)`

Comment: I'd actually much prefer `Array.from( el.parentNode.children ).indexOf( el );` on that instance, just for readability.

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(nodes, node)` works for me.

Answer (score 96):

Here is how I do **(2018 version ?)** :

```
const index = [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el);
```

Tadaaaam. And, if ever you want to consider raw text nodes too, you can do this instead :

```
const index = [...el.parentElement.childNodes].indexOf(el);
```

I spread the children into an array as they are an HTMLCollection (thus they do not work with indexOf).

Be careful that you are using Babel or that browser coverage is sufficient for what you need to achieve (thinkings about the spread operator which is basically an Array.from behind the scene).

Comment: Really cool! Just added `Array.from` to the childNodes respectively `const index = [...Array.from(el.parentElement.children)].indexOf(el);`

Comment: If used as part of an interview - you should mention that Array.from ( or [...] ) will create a shallow copy of the collection - whilst Array.prototype.indexOf.call wont.

Comment: when using `[...el.parentElement.children]`, with typescript, raises the error: _Type 'HTMLCollection' is not an array type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator._

in this case better this approach: `Array.from(el.parentElement.children)`

Comment: It seems this method will have all children into the array, that is to say all siblings of `el`, but this is not always intended and this method doesn't allow to exclude siblings from the array. For instance `el = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.exclude)')`

Comment: @DavidDalBusco, you're creating 2 arrays. If you're using Array.from then just `Array.from(el.parentElement.children).indexOf(el)` is sufficient. No need to create an array and then spread that array into yet another array. Also, while `[...children]` is terse, it is creating a temporary array just for the purpose of searching it and then discarding the temporary. If you want speed then `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(el.parentElement.children, el)` should be faster as no temporary array is created. Speed isn't always important and I'd chose `[...children]` most of the time.

Answer (score 54):

**2017 update**

The original answer below assumes that the OP wants to include non-empty text node and other node types as well as elements. It doesn't seem clear to me now from the question whether this is a valid assumption.

Assuming instead you just want the element index, `previousElementSibling` is now well-supported (which was not the case in 2012) and is the obvious choice now. The following (which is the same as some other answers here) will work in everything major except IE <= 8.

```
function getElementIndex(node) {
    var index = 0;
    while ( (node = node.previousElementSibling) ) {
        index++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

**Original answer**

Just use `previousSibling` until you hit `null`. I'm assuming you want to ignore white space-only text nodes; if you want to filter other nodes then adjust accordingly.

```
function getNodeIndex(node) {
    var index = 0;
    while ( (node = node.previousSibling) ) {
        if (node.nodeType != 3 || !/^\s*$/.test(node.data)) {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is fastest compared to any other method described here. For newer browser, previousElementSibling can be used without these two conditions.

Comment: @bjb568: Is your point that there is a set of unnecessary parentheses?

Comment: Not unnecessary. It's not enough. Everyone knows that you need at least another 7 for beauty.

Comment: @bjb568: Probably best to close them as well.

Comment: @AkashKava correct, previousElementSibling  is the most elegant way.
And technically its not possible that indexOf a node can return -1 anyway. Its either the only element then there is no previousElementSibling and index is 0 or there is a previous element then the index is at least 1

Comment: @bjb568: the double set of parentheses in the while is necessary to prevent JSHint warning 084.

Comment: I added nodeType check to get proper element index: `var nodeType = node.nodeType; ... if (node.nodeType == nodeType && (node.nodeType != 3...`

Comment: @mykola.rykov: I'm probably being stupid but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what does this !/^\s*$/.test(node.data) do exactly?

Comment: why don't you use `previousElementSibling` method instead of testing with regexp?

Comment: @legotin: `previousElementSibling` didn't exist at time of writing. Also, this answer doesn't do exactly the same thing: it assumes the OP wants to know about non-empty text nodes as well. It isn't clear from the question whether this assumption is valid or not.

Comment: @AkashKava How regex can be faster than just to iterate an array???

Answer (score 27):

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this);
```

Or use `let` statement.

Comment: @citykid, sure, it's more terse but it's silly to create a temporary array just to access a function of that array.

Comment: @gman The `indexOf` method does not create a temporary array, unlike many other answers (.slice(), .from(), array spread etc.).  If you look at [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.indexof), it will directly iterate on the children list *as if* it is an array, so it is fast.

Comment: @Sheepy, the comment I was responding to has been deleted. The comment has nothing to do with the answer by Alexander, it has to do with a comment by citykid that suggested `[].indexOf.call(this.parametElement.children, this)`. That does create a temporary array.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this to find the index of an element:

`Array.prototype.indexOf.call(yourUl, yourLi)`

This for example logs all indices:

```
var lis = yourList.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(lis, lis[i]));
}​
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B5Gvu/1/)

Comment: I misinterpreted the question. Edited!

Comment: The [`previousElementSibling` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container#comment29654968_11762728) is better because it will exclude text nodes and will return the index of the element that you expect.

Answer (score 10):

For just elements this can be used to find the index of an element amongst it's sibling elements:

```
function getElIndex(el) {
    for (var i = 0; el = el.previousElementSibling; i++);
    return i;
}
```

Note that `previousElementSibling` isn't supported in IE<9.

Comment: What if it will not be a previous sibling but next?

Comment: @RooticalV.: Not sure what you mean. Did you meant to ask what happens if there is no previous sibling? In that case the loop will automatically exit, since the value of the expression "el = el.previousElementSibling" will be false (as it is null). Or did you meant to ask what would happen if you replaced "previousElementSibling" by "nextElementSibling" in the above code? Well, in that case the loop would count the number of siblings still following the element.

Answer (score 8):

A modern native approach could make use of 'Array.from()' - for example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('get-this-index')
const index = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')).indexOf(el)
document.querySelector('h2').textContent = `index = ${index}`
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>zero
  <li>one
  <li id='get-this-index'>two
  <li>three
</ul>
<h2></h2>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    const nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( el.parentNode.childNodes );
    const index = nodes.indexOf(el);
    console.log('index = ', index);
```

Comment: you could also do `Array.fom` instead of `Array.prototype.slice.call` but the same result

Answer (score 2):

**An example of making an array from HTMLCollection**

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<script>
var tagList = [];

var ulList = document.getElementById("myList");

var tags   = ulList.getElementsByTagName("li");

//Dump elements into Array
while( tagList.length != tags.length){
    tagList.push(tags[tagList.length])
};

tagList.forEach(function(item){
        item.addEventListener("click", function (event){ 
            console.log(tagList.indexOf( event.target || event.srcElement));
        });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the `<li>`s in the `<ul>` and stop when you find the right one.

```
function getIndex(li) {
    var lis = li.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (li === lis[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fNtFu/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write this compactly all you need is:

```
var i = 0;
for (;yourElement.parentNode[i]!==yourElement;i++){}
indexOfYourElement = i;
```

We just cycle through the elements in the parent node, stopping when we find your element.
You can also easily do:

```
for (;yourElement.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("li")[i]!==yourElement;i++){}
```

if that's all you want to look through.

Answer (score 0):

Another example just using a basic loop and index check

**HTML**

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript** *runs onload/ready or after ul is rendered*

```
var list = document.getElementById("foo"),
    items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

list.onclick = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
    src = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var myIndex = findIndex(src);
    alert(myIndex);
};

function findIndex( elem ) {
    var i, len = items.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (items[i]===elem) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Running Example**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmV4c/)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the object reference to the following function and you will get the index

```
function thisindex(elm) 
{ 
    var the_li = elm; 
    var the_ul = elm.parentNode; 
    var li_list = the_ul.childNodes; 

    var count = 0; // Tracks the index of LI nodes

    // Step through all the child nodes of the UL
    for( var i = 0; i < li_list.length; i++ )
    {
        var node = li_list.item(i);
        if( node )
        {
        // Check to see if the node is a LI
            if( node.nodeName == "LI" )
            {
            // Increment the count of LI nodes
                count++;
            // Check to see if this node is the one passed in
                if( the_li == node )
                {
                    // If so, alert the current count
                    alert(count-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```