# Traversing up the dom getting the from a clicked element with id and class

Tags: javascript, html, dom, path, breadcrumbs

I found great information about traversing up the dom getting the node from a clicked element...

[Traversing up the DOM getting the node from a clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998792/traversing-up-the-dom-getting-the-node-from-a-clicked-element?lq=1)

Who can help me to include in the breadcrumb the id= and class= attributes like you see in most buggers?

so instead of:

```
HTML  > BODY  > UL  > LI  > SPAN
```

I would like:

```
HTML  > BODY  > UL.menu  > LI  > SPAN#whatever
```

...or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the [linked code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999047/1558392), the code below will append all ids and classes on the element.

Clicking an element `<div id="id1" class="class1 class2">Test</div>`...

would output **HTML > BODY > DIV#id1.class1.class2**

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    var target = event.target,
    breadcrumb = [];

    while (target) {
        var id = target.id;
        var classes = target.className;
        var crumb = target.tagName;
        if (id) { 
            crumb += "#" + id; 
        }
        if (classes) {
            var classList = classes.split(' ');
            for (var c = 0; c < classList.length; c++) {
                crumb += "." + classList[c];
            }
        }
        breadcrumb.unshift(crumb);
        target = target.parentElement;
    }
    console.log(breadcrumb.join(" > "));
}

document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! It works very good!

can you help me also generatring this path?


/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div

for use with php xpath?