# How to get the Index of an option based on a value

Tags: javascript, html

So I currently have a `select` field that looks something like this:

```
<select id = "foo">
   <option value = "example">This example</option>
   <option value = "example2">This example Again</option>
   <option value = "bar">This is just a bar</option>
</select>
```

and if the submitted form returns back with an error, it sends me back all the values in a object, and I need to repopulate the form.

My question: how can I efficiently get the index of value `bar`, without having to use jQuery?

Is there a way to do it without having to loop through each of the options, checking the value against the one I have, then setting it as checked if it is the same as my value?

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with `index`:

```
var selected = document.querySelector( '#foo > option[value="bar"]' );
console.log(selected.index);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/drssqyes/)

Comment: ooops!  undoing my sin

Comment: This is absolute GOLD! I looked everywhere for something like this! Thanks so much. I'll accept it when SO will let me lol.