# Can you use variables in getElementsByClassName("")[]? And how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to to make the class number selector on `document.getElementsByClassName("photo")[2].setAttribute("id", "current_page");`, i.e. the `2` be a variable.

Here's my real code:
HTML:
`onclick="test(this)"`

And JS:

```js
function test(y) {
 var x = y;
 document.getElementsByClassName("photo")[2].setAttribute("id", "current_page");
}
```

So how can I make the class selector (on example it is `[2]`), a variable?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Switch `2` with the name of your variable?

Comment: You can do `getElementsByClassName("photo")[y].setAttribute`

Comment: You mean you want the second, and later variable, ".photo" element right?

Comment: @PatrickEvans if I do that i get: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName("photo")[y].setAttribute')`

Comment: @MaartenBicknese Patrick was on to what I want to do, replace the `2`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you post html also? i  don't understand which one you have to click?

Comment: @prasad Well, it's php, let me work on it. but for the mean time, all the code is on http://emmetstudios.com/landscape/ , just open up the web inspector.

Comment: Objective, problem and  question are not very clear here. A little more effort in writing up a properly detailed problem statement and question would help us help you

Comment: Because you havent validated that your varible contans a value that is useable, ie the value isnt greater or equal to the length of the collection

Comment: This is due `y` not being a number. It would be wise to check if the element exists before assignment of a new id. And retrieve the index of the clicked element.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11761881/2637098

Comment: if add the attribute `id` at the same element. use like that .`this.setAttribute('id','something')`. In your link all the `photo ` class are same `test(this)`.Then why use with `()[2]`?

Comment: EVERYONE: I'm going to be trying out your solutions, hold tight.

Comment: @prasad Yes it worked! Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: i cant understand what you're trying to to do here. i'm guessing that what you mean is this? `y.setAttribute("id", "current_page")`

Comment: This would have been so much simpler had you provided a [mcve]

Comment: @JeffArries i was added with answer see below

Comment: @charlietfl & EVERYONE: I'm sorry this was confusing, I don't really know my JS, and I didn't know what the `2` in the `[]` meant (the index, as I now know), and I was trying my best to explain it, I'm sorry that it didn't make sense and I thank you all for you support and for trying! ~ Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if add the attribute id at the same element. use like that

```js
function test(that) {
 
 that.setAttribute("id", "current_page");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your requirement from your example, but you can use a variable for the class name:

```
var className = 'photo';    
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
```

Although from your example you seem to want the third element returned by `getElementsByClassName`? To select the nth element, again using a variable, you can do:

```
var elementIndex = 2;
var element = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[elementIndex];
```

Hope I've understood, but add a comment if this isn't what you're trying to get.