# How to get the respective HTML element and its index when clicked on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage. Suppose I don't know that the page contains a `<p>` or any other HTML tag. The script runs in the background  and when I click anywhere on the webpage if there is a corresponding HTML tag to the click  then the script returns the tag with its index number.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click on the tag p then the script should return `<p>` and its index. Somewhat like this:

```
$("body").click(function(){
/* return the clicked html tag within body and its index*/    
});
```

For this:

```
$("tag name").click(function(){
     // return tag
 });
```

I need to know which tag I am clicking on. But I don't know on which tag I'm going to click.

Pure JS  will also do.

Comment: Look at the event object...

Comment: Your question doesn't seem very specific.  We might be able to help if you tell us what problem you are trying to solve!

Comment: @SvenWritesCode edited my post. Tell me if you don't understand

Comment: Note: if you wish to mention HTML tags like `<p>` in a paragraph, wrap them in backticks. This question made little sense prior to my edit, because these tags were rendered as HTML, not text. I recommend using the preview window when composing a post here - it means you can check what your post will look like even before it has been submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use event delegation within the `on` method. http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you provide a selector JQuery will setup the event to fire only when an element within the parent matches that selector. In the below it grabs any element because the selector is `"*"` - this has the added benefit of providing the current clicked element as `this` or `e.currentTarget` within the function call.

```
$("body").on("click", "*", function(e) { alert(this) });
```

To get the index of the specified element within the `body` you can use that `this` context to grab the index based on its `tagName` (a.e. paragraphs have a `tagName` of `p`)

```
$("body").on("click", "*", function(e) { alert(this + " " +  $(this).index(this.tagName))}
```

```js
$("body").on("click", "*", function(e) { alert(this + " " + $(this).index(this.tagName)) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <div>div</div>
    <div>div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: suppose the "p" tag is inside a "div" tag, so when i click on it , it returns all the tags including the div tag which is very obvious, but if i want to get only first tag i.e the tag i clicked then what do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

p is tag contained with body if u use

```
$("body").click(function(){
/* return the clicked html tag within body and its index*/    
});
```

so all of child if you clicks will read body click

if u want click p try it

```
$('p').on('click',function(){});
```

and dont use

```
 $("body").click(function(){
    /* return the clicked html tag within body and its index*/    
    });
```

or u can try it for click p

```
 $('body p').on('click',function(){});
```

Comment: The use of `$("body").click()` is used as a [delegated event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation). That way you don't have to write multiple event handlers for every single element. And OP wants to be able to have the event triggered for any of the elements clicked

Answer (score 0):

The event context returns the html

```js
$('body').click(function(){ var clicked =  $(event.target).context; return clicked;})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p> Nice Body</p>
<p> No pun intended </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you can attach an `onclick` handler to your elements like so:

```
for (let i = 0, len = document.body.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    document.body.children[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(i)  ;
    }
}
```

This will show you the index of the item on the page.

Answer (score -1):

The `event` object that is passed to the event listener contains the element that triggered the event on its [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). So if you need a reference to the element itself just access that property:

```
var element = event.target;
```

If you need the name of the element, for instance `P`, then access the [`nodeName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) of the element object:

```
var name = element.nodeName;
```

Finding the index is just a matter of going through the element's parent's [`children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and seeing which index that element is at. You can do this easily by turning the `children` property into an Array and calling [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) passing in the element

```
Array.from(element.parentElement.children).indexOf(element);
```

---

Demo (note the index is 1 for the P and 2 and 3 for the div's as `<script>` is the first element child)

```js
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var elementName = element.nodeName;
  var index = Array.from(element.parentElement.children).indexOf(element);
  console.log("Element: ", elementName);
  console.log("Index: ", index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much your for the explanation. now it's clear to me.