# How do I get a child element from a div without looping?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I have an element and that element is within a parent div. I want to see what the child id is of this element, preferably without looping. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the children set of its parent to an array and look for the index:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('xxx');

const index = [...element.parentElement.children].indexOf(element);
```

Comment: Best answer, no loop needed. Love it. I did get confused by the 3 dots tho. What do they do?

Comment: @MikeOttink The three dots here is for object destruction, then wrap it in squarely brackets to make a array out of them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do for more information