# How to achieve the same behaviour in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a **drag n drop** simple project. Trying to get the **javascript code** to get the index of the dragged item. After searching found a similar code in **jquery**.

```
var index = $(e.target).index();
```

I want to get this done in javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="lists">
   <div class="list">
     <div class="list-item">Item 1</div>
     <div class="list-item">Item 2</div>
     <div class="list-item">Item 3</div>
     <div class="list-item">Item 4</div>
     <div class="list-item">Item 5</div>
   </div>
   <div class="list"></div>
   <div class="list"></div>
 </div>
```

This is the code im working on

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript. Do you mean, get this done in vanilla JavaScript (no libraries)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Comment: @Amadan i want the DOM way to do it

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#index

Comment: @Yoshi Good link. Another possibility is to assign numbers to attributes of the elements when they are generated, which results in a larger HTML but faster lookup.

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.target.parentElement.children, e.target)`

Comment: You've pulled this line of code out from the context it lived in, it doesn't mean very much on its own. What you want looks like it would be extremely simple but it would be helpful to actually provide the surrounding code if you want a solution - what @Thomas posted is probably the exact thing you need, but your code still doesn't make a whole lotta sense in isolation

Comment: @lucifer_096 You can check this example https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gbdwjj