# How to get a index of class onhover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following `div` structure:

```
<div class="0">
     <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="1">
     <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="2">
     <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div class="3">
     <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

For example, if I hover on the 1st class: `document.getElementbyClassName('test')[0]`, I should get index value is 0.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a pure JS solution

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761881/javascript-dom-find-element-index-in-container)

Comment: Note for the future, if you're looking for a pure JS solution do not tag your questions as 'jQuery'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
$('.test').mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("index: " + $(this).index('.test'));
})
```

```js
$('.test').mouseenter(function() {
  console.log("index: " + $(this).index('.test'));
})
```

```css
.test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Can i get answered in Javascript?

Comment: @Sai But why did you mark your question with jquery then?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in pure JS you can use `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve the target elements and bind a `mouseenter` event handler to them. Then you can find the index of the element which triggered the event by comparing it to the collection of children in the parent. Something like this:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  let index = Array.from(elements).indexOf(e.target);
  console.log(index);
}));
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="test">Test 1</div>
</div>
<div class="2">
  <div class="test">Test 2</div>
</div>
<div class="3">
  <div class="test">Test 3</div>
</div>
<div class="4">
  <div class="test">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="1">
<div class="test">Test 1</div>
</div>`
`<div class="2">
<div class="test">Test 2</div>
</div>`
`<div class="3">
<div class="test">Test 3</div>
</div>`
`<div class="4">
<div class="test">Test 4</div>
</div>`

Thanks! but what if class='test' is child of different parents. 
Then how to find the index ?

Comment: In that case you could use the `elements` collection directly, although note that this will only work if you have a single group of `.test` elements.

Comment: Thank you! so much Rory, It's working fine .

Answer (score -1):

This code Use pure java script :

```js
    var divItems = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
    var mytab = [];
    var index = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < divItems.length; i++) {
      mytab.push(divItems[i].innerHTML);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < divItems.length; i++) 
    {
      divItems[i].onmouseover = function () 
      {
         index = mytab.indexOf(this.innerHTML);
         console.log(this.innerHTML + " Index = " + index);
      };
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">Hover me 1</div>
<div class="test">Hover me 2</div>
<div class="test">Hover me 3</div>
<div class="test">Hover me 4</div>
```

Comment: The mix of `var i` and `let i` is questionable.