# get actual computed style from pseudo element (:before)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is when I use the offered solutions, like `window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(Element), '::before').getPropertyValue('content');` in my specific case I am getting `counter(paragraph)` and not the actual number of the paragraph, shown on my site. Maybe you have an other idea how to approach this problem?

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
    <p>TExttextlalalalalalalala</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
li:before {
    content: counter(paragraph);
    counter-increment: paragraph;
}
```

Edit:
I need this for a search function, which lists the results with a verse number. A direct access would be easier and more efficient than my current solution:

```
function getVerseNumber(liElement) {
const liElements = liElement.closest('ol').querySelectorAll('li');
const verseNumber = Array.from(liElements).indexOf(liElement) + 1;
return verseNumber;}
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need it?

Comment: One liner to get the element's index based on the parent. `const getIndex = (el) => {return [...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el)+1}` original https://stackoverflow.com/a/49646841/3684265

Comment: @imvain2 thank you! I will go with ```Array.prototype.indexOf.call(el.parentElement.children, el)``` from the same thread for now.