# jQuery index() in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per the jQuery api, the complementary operation to .get(), which accepts an index and returns a DOM node, `.index()` can take a DOM node and returns an index. Suppose we have a simple unordered list on the page:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>
```

`.index()` will return the position of the first element within the set of matched elements in relation to its siblings:

```
alert('Index: ' + $('#bar').index();
```

We get back the zero-based position of the list item:

```
Index: 1
```

I just want to know, how can we do the same using **JavaScript**??

Comment: I'm not suggesting  you should always use jQuery, but out of curiosity, why do you want to do this in pure JS?

Comment: @JamWaffles: I use jQuery mostly, due to its "The Write Less, Do More" nature. So, I had asked this question just for my knowledge and let others know, what "The Write Less, Do More" really means from this example. Hope you got my point!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding DOM node index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378365/finding-dom-node-index)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It should be noted that the answers in the listed duplicate look for the index without testing the type of the node (which may be a text for example). That's why they don't return the same result than jquery's index (as is the question) which is what is generally useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can build your own function :

```
function indexInParent(node) {
    var children = node.parentNode.childNodes;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
         if (children[i]==node) return num;
         if (children[i].nodeType==1) num++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/QNRd6/)

Comment: Really like this answer! Why do you need to end off with `return -1`? The code will never hit that. If you pass an invalid element, you will get an error.

Comment: @Jessica The usual convention for `index` functions is to return `-1` when an element isn't found, not an error (or `undefined` as it would be without the last line)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the source for jquery's `index()` is?

Comment: Why not use parentNode.children instead of parentNode.childNodes? It could allow using indexOf instead of increasing num manually.

Answer (score 22):

I've modified [Travis J answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13658041/104380) to not include TextNodes and made a function out of it.

You can run it in the console and see (on stackoverflow).

### Classic way:

```js
function getNodeIndex( elm ){ 
    var c = elm.parentNode.children, 
        i = c.length;
        
    while(i--) 
      if( c[i] == elm ) 
        return i
}
```

### With ES2015:

```js
const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].findIndex(c => c == elm)

// or

const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)
```

#### Demo:

```js
const getNodeIndex = elm => [...elm.parentNode.children].indexOf(elm)
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(  getNodeIndex(this)  )">get index</button>
<button onclick="console.log(  getNodeIndex(this)  )">get index</button>
<button onclick="console.log(  getNodeIndex(this)  )">get index</button>
```

---

I also want to point to another thread on the same matter, which has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762728/104380) (for people seeking older IE support)

Answer (score 11):

No loops needed, call `Array#indexOf` on `.parentElement.children`:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#baz');

[].indexOf.call(element.parentElement.children, element);
// => 2
```

You can even call it on a random list of elements, just like you can in jQuery:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('li');
const element = document.querySelector('#baz');

[].indexOf.call(list, element);
// => 2
```

Comment: This should be more highly upvoted, it accomplishes the same thing as all of the other answers do in a single line of code - brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information out by going up the dom tree using previousElementSibling and incrementing.

```
var getElementIndex(element) {
    if (!element) {
        return -1;
    }
    var currentElement = element,
        index = 0;

    while(currentElement.previousElementSibling) {
        index++;
        currentElement = currentElement.previousElementSibling;
    }
    return index
}

getElementIndex(document.getElementById('#bar'));
```

here is the browser support for previousElementSibling:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling

Answer (score 0):

Index can be found in this way

```
    Array.from(children).findIndex(element => element.id === "bar")
```