# jQuery `index()` equivalent in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the below code snippet (`currentUser` class is on a different list item depending on who is viewing the page).

```
<ul>
    <li>user 1</li>
    <li>user 2</li>
    <li class="currentUser">user 3</li>
    <li>user 4</li>
</ul>

var curLth = jQuery('.currentUser').index();
console.log(curLth); //outputs 2
```

The site I am working on does not load jQuery, so I want to know which list item has the class `currentUser` without using jQuery

I have inspected the `NodeList` in the dev tools but haven't seen anything that I can use to get this.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .index() in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658021/jquery-index-in-javascript)

Comment: @artm thanks for that link.  I was having a look around but obviously was using the best search terms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the equivalant:

```
var curUser = document.getElementsByClassName("currentUser")[0];
var curLth = [].slice.call(curUser.parentNode.children).indexOf(curUser);
console.log(curLth); //outputs 2
```

Comment: nowadays we can use `Array.from(curUser.parentNode.children).indexOf(curUser);`