# How to determine which child image was clicked within a parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which prompts the user to select an image:

```
<div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
  <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
  <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person1.jpg" alt="" onclick ="ShowNext();" >
  <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person2.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext();">
  <img class = "quizImg"src="images/person3.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext();">
  <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person4.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext();">
</div>
```

Upon clicking the image I would like to determine which image was clicked.

Is there a way to retrieve the index of the image somehow ?
(for instance if person1 was clicked the index would be 0 or 1)?

I know I can assign IDs to each image but would like to know if there is an easier route.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658021/jquery-index-in-vanilla-javascript

Comment: Event.target points to the target, element triggering the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array#indexOf` to find the index of a clicked image in the array of all images:

```js
var images = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#frame1 > .quizImg'), 0); // get all images inside frame1, and convert to array

function ShowNext(img) {   
  console.log(images.indexOf(img)); // find the index of the clicked image inside the array
}
```

```html
<div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
  <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="" onclick ="ShowNext(this);" >
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
  <img class = "quizImg"src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
</div>
```

---

Or using `.addEventListener()` with event delegation:

```js
var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1'); // find the images container
var images = [].slice.call(frame1.querySelectorAll('.quizImg'), 0); // get all images inside frame1, and convert to array

frame1

 // add an event listener that will handle all clicks inside frame1
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
   // find the index of the clicked target from the images array
  var index = images.indexOf(e.target)
  
  if(index !== -1) { // if no image was clicked
    console.log(index);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
  <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
  <img class = "quizImg"src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
  <img class = "quizImg" src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: This provides a potential solution but i would like to retrieve only the images within frame 1. Rather than retrieving all of the images with class ".quizImg" is there any way to retrieve an array of the 4 images specifically within frame 1?

Comment: Sure you can search inside a container - `document.querySelectorAll('#frame1 > .quizImg')`. See edit.

Comment: Thank you! Was searching for this from days.

Answer (score 4):

Click event has `.target` attribute that shows actual clicked element.

```js
document.getElementById("frame1").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // display the current click count inside the clicked div
  event.target.className = "clicked";
}, false);

function ShowNext() {

}
```

```css
.clicked {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
img {
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame1" class="quizFrame quizFrame1">
  <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
  <img class="quizImg" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" onclick="ShowNext();">
  <img class="quizImg" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" onclick="ShowNext();">
  <img class="quizImg" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" onclick="ShowNext();">
  <img class="quizImg" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" alt="" onclick="ShowNext();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('src'); // it will return source : images/personal1.jpg if clicked on first one
});
```

Comment: 1. There is no jQuery in the question 2. "_Is there a way to retrieve **the index** of the image somehow_"

Answer (score 1):

Pass this with every function call:

```
<div id="frame1" class = "quizFrame quizFrame1">
    <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
    <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person1.jpg" alt="" onclick ="ShowNext(this);" >
    <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person2.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
    <img class = "quizImg"src="images/person3.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
    <img class = "quizImg" src="images/person4.jpg" alt="" onclick = "ShowNext(this);">
</div>
```

Here is Javascript code to retrieve value from  tag:

```
var Imgs = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('frame1').children);
function ShowNext(element){
    console.log(Imgs.indexOf(element));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on parent element so that the click event is delegated to it's children (images). The handler is function `indentify()` which uses the [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/images) property to collect all the images. Next it iterates through a `for` loop and finds the exact image clicked by using the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) property to compare the index number of the clicked element.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var f1 = document.getElementById('frame1');

f1.addEventListener('click', identify, false);

function identify(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    if (document.images[i] === e.target) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="frame1" class="quizFrame quizFrame1">
  <p>Which image do you identify with?</p>
  <img class="quizImg" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=1" alt="">
  <img class="quizImg" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=2" alt="">
  <img class="quizImg" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=3" alt="">
  <img class="quizImg" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/000/fff?text=4" alt="">
</div>
```