# close all items when one is open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi i tried to close all items when i click on one like GIF shows but i couldn't find a solution to this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlgMJ.gif)

Children are hiden now :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6gny.gif)

This is my JS code :

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
    var EltToToggle_parent =  EltToToggle.parents('.sub-menu');

    $(".sub-menu .sub-menu").not(EltToToggle).hide();
    // $(".sub-menu").hide();
    EltToToggle.fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('activu');
      return false;
  });
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<ul>
   <li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1555">
      <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">Nos métiers :  Fonctions support</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1673" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1673">
                <a href="#">Test insertion shortcode tableau RWD – Alex</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-1600" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1600 menu-item-has-children">
                <a href="# " aria-expanded="false" class="btnForExpanding">testu</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-1656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1656">
                       <a href="#">Test de tableau – page – style 3 Empilement Stacking</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-1556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1556">
        <a href="https://jobs.cegid-webfactory.dev.ci.alterway.fr/fr/experiences-enrichissantes/nos-metiers-customer-care/">Nos métiers : Customer Care</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS for the arrow icon not for showing or hiding item :

```
 .activu {
    font-weight: $fw-semiBold;

    &:after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open only 1 accordion at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849514/how-to-open-only-1-accordion-at-one-time)

Comment: this is vanilla javascript solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158000/13411051

Comment: @A.Meshu nop :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide every `.sub-menu` but not the `.sub-menu` wich are children of the current `.menu-item`

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
  var notToHide = $(this).parents('.menu-item').find('.sub-menu');
     
  $(".sub-menu").not(notToHide).hide();
  EltToToggle.fadeToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('activu');
   return false;
});
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4o6t2La/)

Comment: so there are still many .activu elements in your document after the function run?

Comment: .activu is just a class that change the arrow, it's not display or show the item, please see the css that i added

Comment: now i got your point. I´v updated the anwser

Comment: now it hide children ! please see my post i added a Gif

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: I´ll reconstructed this issue in a jsfiddle and provide you an anwser in few minutes

Comment: Does this fit your requirements?

Comment: No problem. It was a little bit hard to fix at the beginning without a stackblitz or fiddle.

Comment: Thank you Martin, i appreciate yoir help :)

Answer (score 0):

before `e.preventDefault();` add this line `$(".activu").removeClass("activu");`

Comment: Check in the console which class is added when you click on the submenu. You need to remove this class. Probably it is not the "activu" class.

Comment: Fernando Del Cantao there is no class added. Jquery.fadeToggle is animating the opacity of the element inline without any classes

Comment: there is no class, it just the `fadeToggle()` that shows or hide items