# Finding Dom Node Index for elements of a certain class of a multi-class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, indexing

Hi I have a series of  tags with multiple different classes. When a span is clicked I want to return the index of the class of spans. So not the index of the spans themselves.

Here is a sample html:

```
<span class='spantype1 party'>text1</span>
<span class='spantype2 party'>text2</span>
<span class='spantype1 party'>text3</span>
```

So if I click on text3 I want to return 1 not 2. If I click on text1 I want to return 0. And of course if I click on text2 I want to return 0.

This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003374/finding-dom-node-index-for-elements-of-a-certain-class) doesn't work because index is always returned as -1 (because there are multiple classes), see [my example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puLNt/10/):

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    var index = $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).index($(this));
    alert(index);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a filter to grab the class you're interested in, and search based on that:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    var spanType = $.grep(this.classList, function (className) {
        return /^spantype/.test(className);
    })[0];

    var index = $('.' + spanType).index($(this));
    alert(index);
});
```

I used `classList` above, but for better support (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/classlist)), you could probably use `className` instead:

```
$("span").click(function() {
    var spanType = $.grep(this.className.split(/\s+/), function (className) {
        return /^spantype/.test(className);
    })[0];

    var index = $('.' + spanType).index($(this));
    alert(index);
});
```