# Finding Dom Node Index for elements of a certain class prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a series of  tags with different classes. When a span is clicked I want to return the index of the class of spans. So not the index of the spans themselves.

Here is a sample html:

```
<span class='spantype1_a'>text1</span>
<span class='spantype2_b'>text2</span>
<span class='spantype1_c'>text3</span>
```

So if I click on text3 I want to return 1 not 2.

This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003374/finding-dom-node-index-for-elements-of-a-certain-class) doesn't work because each span has a unique class so 0 is returned, see [the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/puLNt/13/):

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    var index = $('.' + $(this).attr('class')).index($(this));
    alert(index);
});
```

Also, the below code returns -1, see [the example jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/puLNt/13/):

```
$( "span" ).click(function() {
    var aclass = $(this).attr('class');
    var back = aclass.lastIndexOf("_");
    var classtosearch = aclass.substring(0, back);
    alert($('.' + 'span[class^="' + classtosearch + '"]').index($(this)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change:

```
alert($('.' + 'span[class^="' + classtosearch + '"]').index($(this)));
```

to:

```
alert($('span[class^="' + classtosearch + '"]').index($(this)));
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/puLNt/15/).

Comment: I would but stack overflow won't let me until two days have passed.